# Is there a way to find web data services?

Tags: wcf, web-services, dataservice

Is there any way to take a website and find their web data service? What I mean is trying to find for instance a WCF Service with out having any prior knowledge of its existence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websites with web-services include a 'WSDL' or 'WADL' page, so you can use Google Advanced Search to search for pages that include wsdl OR wadl in the URL and limit the search to the site you're interested in.  For example:

```
allinurl:  wsdl OR wadl site:ec.europa.eu
```

This finds the web-service for the European Commission's website:

```
ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl
```

Comment: Do all services including Java type services use wsdl to configure it?

Comment: The language binding doesn't matter.  However, REST services may alternatively use WADL, instead of WSDL.  I will update my answer to reflect that.